# How can I dump or export row level security policies from a Postres database?

Tags: postgresql, supabase, row-level-security

I'm using Supabase and defined several row level security policies in their UI. Now I'd like to download or export all the policies to review and/or edit them.

I found documentation on querying the pg_policy table, but that seems to store the policies in a difficult to read format. Ideally the output would be a list of `CREATE POLICY...` statements to reproduce the current policies.

Comment: `pg_dump` certainly does dump them. pgAdmin4 can also display them, using SQL syntax, but probably not in an automatable way.

Comment: `psql` will display the policies as well. If you start with the `--echo-hidden`  parameter you can see the queries it uses to do that.

Answer (score 2):

As Bergi pointed out in the comment, `pg_dump` will list the policies as SQL, and the `-s` option will limit the output to the database schema and exlude the data.